# Symfony : start process and display console output line by line in view

Tags: symfony

Regarding [Symfony Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html), when running a command, i can acess in real-time to each console output, no problem.

While collecting these informations in a controller, i want to render them in a view, one after an other.

What concept should I look for to achieve this ?

Comment: OK, given the vast scope of the question, please give us some rundown of your own thoughts. Maybe we could fill out the blanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you fully grasp how the controller Request / Response paradigm works. A single request comes in, then a single response is given. There are ways to accomplish what you want but its involved.

High overview would be something like:

- Have the output of the command logged to a file
- Setup a route and controller action that takes a starting line number as an argument

  - The method reads the file and returns all new lines since then.
- On the front end of the site setup some sort of polling AJAX request that requests the new route and passes the last line number its received.